# Delay between Application.ScreenUpdating = True/False to show the change

Tags: vba, excel

I have this problem: My code runs in Application.ScreenUpdating = False but at some moments, I need to show the "progress message" to the user.

I have this code:

```
Sub CommentUpdate(TextBoxName As Object, CommentMessage As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
TextBoxName.Text = CommentMessage
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

But when it's running inside my whole program, it doesn't work. If I do it step by step in the VBA Editor (via F8), it works and I see the change.

I suspect that in the general code, this instruction (the switch between True/False) is too fast and the screen has no time to update.

Adding of 1 second waiting time to the procedre didn't help...
Any ideas?

Comment: @me how: yes, I did and no improvement. I reformulated my quastion...

Comment: Have you tried switching commands order? Put `TextBoxName.Text...` as first command.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons this is not happening.

- **Check for events in your loop:** If the loop is running through too quickly, you may not be able to notice the change. For that, you may want to run an `Application.DoEvents()` line inside your loop. That would slow it down but should update the screen.
- **Redraw the entire UserForm:** If there is pending activity in your code pertaining to the `UserForm`, the form may not be updated till it's complete. In that case, you may want to try: `UserForm1.Repaint`

The `RePaint` method should refresh the contents including textboxes, etc. to display the updated values.